# Unix code ish, not a date but an amount of time

Tags: unix

I can't find anything on the internet on how to convert thees strange numbers in an amount of time.
http://old.hivemc.com/json/sky/e698edd3e0124b2f8fa2ccb109b0d0b0 Tells me that time alive is 363038.
That same link with 'Splegg' instead of 'sky' Tells me that time alive is 706638.
That same link with 'survivalgamessolo' instead of 'sky' Tells me that time alive is 1074.
That same link with 'survivalgames' tells me that 472252 is the time alive.

https://hive.tools/survivalgames// tells me that 472252 is 5d 11h 10m 52s.
That same link with 'splegg' instead of 'survivalgames' tells me that 706638 is 8d 04h 17m 18s.

I still don't know what 'survivalgamessolo' and 'sky' times are.

Comment: could you perhaps add what each code has to mean? Eg your first number could mean year,month,day,hour,minute etc. while the last numbers could just mean hours minutes. (Not thinking about the restrictions in terms of 60mins / hour atm)

Comment: What's the source of these numbers?

Answer (score 1):

That number is time in seconds

```
472252 seconds =   5d 11h 10m 52sec
               =   ( 5 * 24 * 60 * 60)
                 + (11 * 60 * 60)
                 + (10 * 60)
                 + 52

706638 seconds =   8d 04h 17m 18sec

So 1074 seconds = (1074 / 60 )
                = 17.9 min
                = 17 min 54 sec
```